# Flex Builder: I want to go from titleWindow to a panel

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder

I'm building a user login page and I want to go from titleWindow to Panel.
I'm using the following function but it always takes me back to parentApplication.

My question is how can I go to my panel and not to Application page?

I know that I'm using parentApplication but what should I use instead?

Here is a part of my code:

```
private function handleLogin(event:ResultEvent):void {
            Alert.show("You have succesfully logged in.", "Information", Alert.OK, null, null, null, Alert.OK);   

            parentApplication.accountPage.mainService.getAccount();                          
            PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
        }
```

Comment: What Panel are you talking about? What do you mean by "going" to the panel? just showing it?

Comment: Be careful, that is some seriously tight coupling there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a parent container to hold some `child-mxmls`, you can establish connections between the parent and children like this:

```
(this.parentDocument as yourParentContainer's id).childContainer's id
```

I always use this linking when working on a page that is currently in background or when I collect some data on one page and send it to the other page before it comes up in front of the user.